# What is the basis of the Jehovah's Witnesses' belief that Jesus died on a Stake instead of a Cross?

Tags: life-of-jesus, jehovahs-witnesses, crucifixion, cross

I understand that the Jehovah's Witnesses teach that Jesus died on a Stake (a vertical pole) instead of a Cross.    What is the basis—biblical or other—for this belief?  Does history and archaeology show that the Roman form of crucifixion used just a vertical pole instead of a cross?  Was this unique to Jesus' death alone?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Crucifixion -- torture stake or cross?](https://christianity.stackexchange.com/questions/2109/crucifixion-torture-stake-or-cross)

Answer (score 7):

The Jehovah's Witnesses have addresses this issue. From their web site:
https://www.jw.org/en/bible-teachings/questions/did-jesus-die-on-cross/

> Many view the cross as the most common symbol of Christianity.
>   However, the Bible does not describe the instrument of Jesus’ death,
>   so no one can know its shape with absolute certainty. Still, the Bible
>   provides evidence that Jesus died, not on a cross, but on an upright
>   stake.
>
> The Bible generally uses the Greek word *stau·ros′* when referring to
>   the instrument of Jesus’ execution. ([Matthew 27:40](https://www.jw.org/en/publications/bible/nwt/books/matthew/27/#v40027040); [John
>   19:17](https://www.jw.org/en/publications/bible/nwt/books/john/19/#v43019017)) Although translations often render this word “cross,” many
>   scholars agree that its basic meaning is actually “upright stake.” *
>   According to *A Critical Lexicon and Concordance to the English and
>   Greek New Testament,* *stau·ros′* “never means two pieces of wood
>   joining each other at any angle.”
>
> The Bible also uses the Greek word *xy′lon* as a synonym for
>   *stau·ros′.* ([Acts 5:30](https://www.jw.org/en/publications/bible/nwt/books/acts/5/#v44005030); [1 Peter 2:24](https://www.jw.org/en/publications/bible/nwt/books/1-peter/2/#v60002024)) This word means “wood,” “timber,” “stake,” or “tree.” * *The Companion Bible* thus
>   concludes: “There is nothing in the Greek of the N[ew] T[estament]
>   even to imply two pieces of timber.”